# Is SOAP or OPC XML-DA specification requires to use utf-8?

Tags: xml, soap, encoding, utf-8, opc

I have a linux machine and I'm using PyOPC to connect to OPC Servers. I can see that PyOPC always use utf-8 encoding and in all examples of soap messages and such using utf-8 are used.

Is that a part of specification or what? Because I need to connect to server that can't receive messages in utf-8 and want to use Latin-1 encoding and I don't know what is the right thing to do here. Try to somehow change PyOPC so that it would use Latin-1 or should the server side fellows change their server so that it would receive utf-8 encoded messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OPC XML-DA Specification does not dictate the use of UTF-8 (or any other encoding). Therefore it is left to the client and server implementors which encodings they choose to support.

The formal WSDL schemas in the spec are in UTF-8 but that should have no influence on their semantics, i.e. on the encoding of the messages the schemas describe.

Note that if, in reality, you just need to transfer data that only contain plain English/ASCII subset, then Latin-1 and UTF-8 would be practically equivalent, and you can therefore "pretend" on one or the other side that you understand the other encoding, while simply treating it as already being the one that you have support for.